# Google signing from Android with auto fill with given email id

Tags: android, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

In my android device I have logged in with google account A (example:-a@gmail.com).

In my app before I have my initial login screen from there I'm going to google flow based on provided email.

If I provide a@gmail.com(this account already logged in my device google account) then I able to go forward without asking the google account chooser list.

But If I provided some other y@gmail.com (which my device didn't register) then it is navigating to account chooser screen from there I can choose select another account option (basically I want skip this account chooser). I got to know that we can use "login_hint" option for the same, but I didn't get how to use.

I followed this
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/

similar way I'm trying to connect to google.

GoogleSignInOptions, GoogleSignInAccount etc.

how can we bypass the account chooser list with non registered account while signing with google.

Comment: Any suggestion for this